# Mirror/Duplicate mouse action javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom, mouseevent

Here is my fiddle

```js
handler = function(e) {
  new_e = new e.constructor(e.type, e.originalEvent);

  console.log(new_e.type)
    //var ev = new Event("look", new_e);
  document.getElementById("box2").dispatchEvent(new_e);
}
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
box1.addEventListener('dragstart', handler);
box1.addEventListener('dragend', handler);
box1.addEventListener('drag', handler);
box1.addEventListener('click', handler);
box1.addEventListener('dblclick', handler);
box1.addEventListener('mousedown', handler);
box1.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);
box1.addEventListener('mouseover', handler);
box1.addEventListener('mouseout', handler);
box1.addEventListener('mousemove', handler);

//var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
//box2.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) { console.log('Entered into #box2'); });
//box2.addEventListener('dragend', function(e) { console.log('Leaving #box2'); });
```

```html
<div id="box1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: navy;">test test test test test</div>
<div id="box2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green;">test test test test test</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dilip/8295uxzk/

What I am trying to achieve is, I need to capture all the mouse actions from one container(Div) to another.  Like if I select text from `clientX:10` to `clientX:40` on the first div it should select the same on the other div with position `clientX:10` to `clientX:40`

In order to achieve the above I made a small code.
In the above example If I select the text on the blue box it should select the text on the green box by cloning the mouse events. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the tracking seems to work...

Comment: Yes the tracking works, but the green box is not moving with my mouse..:(

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would make that happen.  For that matter, even the blue box doesn't actually "drag".  It just goes ghost and goes along with the mouse - then snaps back when the button lifts.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I agree that is a goest that appears.  What I am trying to say is I need the same action happening on the other div.  Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Dilip/8295uxzk/2/  when I select the text on div 1 it should select the text on div 2

Comment: I have updated my description.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can not select multiple strings at once.  You can highlight or otherwise change the look of the two strings, but I think the 'mouse' string selection function you are referring to is inherently a single string - even if you do it programmatically.  There are methods that refer to 'the selected' text, and if there is more than one of those, I don't know how they would work.

Here is some [discussion of selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), and I am inferring that there is ONE node on which a selection can occur on a given DOM.

However, my approach would be to use other kinds of highlighting on both divs when a selection is detected.  Then, you can create new elements to 'ghost' across the screen when a drag is detected.